# How can I present these DNA sequences within a table using \pbox?

Tags: tables, tabularx, hyphenation, parbox

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now.

I have a table containing some DNA sequences, `tabularx` couldn't figure out where to hyphenate the sequence and the table ran out of the margins of the page. To remedy this, I tried using the `pbox` package and hyphenating the sequence manually, with limited success. 
The code for each table row is identical, but the top portion of the table overlaps the bottom — I can't seem to figure out why.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|} 
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{TruSeq Adapter Sequences.}} \\
    \hline
    & \textbf{Read 1} & \textbf{Read 2} \\
    \hline 
        \textbf{Forward Adapter} & \small{\pbox[t][0.3cm]{4cm}{AGATCGGAAGAGCACAC-\\GTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC}} & \small{\pbox[t][0.3cm]{4cm}{AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCG-\\TGTAGGGAAAGAGTGT}} \\
        & & \\
    \hline 
        \textbf{Reverse Compliment} & \small{\pbox[t][0.3cm]{4cm}{TCTAGCCTTCTCGTGT-\\GCAGACTTGAGGTCAGTG}} & \small{\pbox[t][0.3cm]{4cm}{TCTAGCCTTCTCGCAG-\\CACATCCCTTTCTCACA}} \\
        & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: And what is `\pbox`? Please always post full minimal examples instead of sniplets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\seqsplit` command, from the homonymous package, or for a more sophisticated package, `dnaseq`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, seqsplit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering\setcellgapes{0.5ex}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{TruSeq Adapter Sequences.}} \\
\hline
& \textbf{Read 1} & \textbf{Read 2} \\
\hline
    \textbf{Forward Adapter} & \small\seqsplit{AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC}& \small\seqsplit{AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGT} \\
\hline
 \textbf{Reverse Compliment} & \small\seqsplit{TCTAGCCTTCTCGTGTGCAGACTTGAGGTCAGTG} & \small\seqsplit{TCTAGCCTTCTCGCACACATCCCTTTCTCACA} \\
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulations for your 200K!

Comment: Thanks so much, @egreg!

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about the `dnaseq` package - very useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a “hand-made” sequence split macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second realization

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sequence}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \linebreak[0] }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{A caged table}

\medskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{TruSeq Adapter Sequences.}} \\
\hline
& \textbf{Read 1} & \textbf{Read 2} \\
\hline 
\textbf{Forward Adapter} & 
  \sequence{AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC} &
  \sequence{AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGT} \\
\hline 
\textbf{Reverse Complement} &
  \sequence{TCTAGCCTTCTCGTGTGCAGACTTGAGGTCAGTG} &
  \sequence{TCTAGCCTTCTCGCAGCACATCCCTTTCTCACA} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{An uncaged table}

\medskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{TruSeq Adapter Sequences.}} \\
\midrule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Read 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Read 2}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\textbf{Forward Adapter} & 
  \sequence{AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC} &
  \sequence{AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGT} \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Reverse Complement} &
  \sequence{TCTAGCCTTCTCGTGTGCAGACTTGAGGTCAGTG} &
  \sequence{TCTAGCCTTCTCGCAGCACATCCCTTTCTCACA} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The `\sequence` macro stores the input in a sequence and then delivers it adding a feasible line break point between any two items, with `\linebreak[0]`.

I warmly suggest the bottom style.

[image]