# Nucleotide sequences exceed table

Tags: tables

My problem is that the nucleotide sequences do not stay within the table using Overleaf. The table is not the best and I simply wanted to illustrate the problem.

[image: Output of the code]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}p{3cm}p{8cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{list of oligonucleotides} \\
\hline
& primer ID & AAP1\\
dual sgRNA & RRB008_fw 5'-3’
& ATATATGGTCTCGATTGCACGATAAAGGGCACACTGGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAATAGC\\
dual sgRNA & RRB008_rev 5'-3' & 
ATTATTGGTCTCGAAACCTGTGCCCGTCATACTCGTCAAATCTCTTAGTCGACTCTAC\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome. // A problem is, that your words, typographically speaking, are too long, and Latex got no indication, where to break it. // Can you switch to landscape? Will your entries vary even more, i.e. create even longer rows?

Comment: If hyphenation of your sequences is an option, you can define useful hyphens via \hyphenation{} , see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation // Or, if that is an option, insert a space, e.g. each 5th or 7th character. // Ross‘ suggestion is even better.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520908

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with the `seqsplit` package. I added some improvements, as the default vertical spacing in tables is very tight, using the `cellspace` package, which lets you define a minimal vertical spacing at the top  & bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, or any letter you please through a loading time option).

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{seqsplit}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |S{p{2cm}}S{p{3cm}}S{p{8cm}}| }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|Sc|}{list of oligonucleotides} \\
    \hline
    & primer ID & AAP1\\
    dual sgRNA & RRB008\textsubscript{fw 5'-3’}
    & \seqsplit{ATATATGGTCTCGATTGCACGATAAAGGGCACACTGGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAATAGC}\\
    dual sgRNA & RRB008\textsubscript{rev 5'-3'} &
    \seqsplit{ATTATTGGTCTCGAAACCTGTGCCCGTCATACTCGTCAAATCTCTTAGTCGACTCTAC}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I do not get an output like yours no matter what I do. However, I have found a way. Would upvote your answer, but I need a higher reputation for this.

Comment: @cinyatta: maybe in your peamble you load packages that have some incompatibilies. That's on of the reasons why it is better to post complete compilable code, with document class and packages loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to keep sequences without broken lines, you could just gather groups and separate them by an extra space. Because sequences are quite long, rotating the table might also help

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}      % improved column specification
\usepackage{booktabs}   % adds toprule, bottomrule, midrule, and addlinespace
\usepackage{rotating}   % for \rotatebox{}{}
\usepackage{caption}    % improved captioning
    \captionsetup[table]{position=bottom, skip=12pt}

%%% For demonstration
\usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
    \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \centering
    \rotatebox{90}{%
        \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}<{:} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{Terms}  & Details \\
            \midrule
            Name      & dual sgRNA \\
            primer ID & RRB008\textsubscript{fw} 5'-3’ \\
            AAP1      & ATATATGGTCTCGATTGCAC-GATAAAGGGCACACTGGTTTTA-GAGCTAGAAATAGC \\ \addlinespace[12pt]
            Name      & dual sgRNA \\
            primer ID & RRB008\textsubscript{rev} 5'-3' \\
            AAP1      & ATTATTGGTCTCGAAACCTGTGCCCGTCATACTCGTCAAATCTCTTAGTCGACTCTAC \\ \addlinespace[12pt]
            Name      & etc. \\
            primer ID & etc. \\
            AAP1      & etc. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}
    \caption{list of oligonucleotides}\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```